# Issue selecting different Chrome windows in Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: gnome, 20.04

When I was using Ubuntu 18.04, if I had multiple Chrome windows open (which I do every day), and I clicked on the Chrome icon on the shortcut bar, it would bring up a little selector letting me pick which window is brought into focus.

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.1 the other day, now when I click on the Chrome icon, rather than bring up a selector, it just brings a seemingly random Chrome window into focus. Clicking a second time will bring up the selector. I use Chrome as an example but this happens to other apps as well.

Is there a way I can restore the previous behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the terminal and use the code **$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'preview'**. This worked for me and I hope it helps you too.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - unfortunately I don't use the dash to dock extension so this doesn't help me I'm afraid.